# htmlUnit - How to get non-element content

Tags: java, web-crawler, htmlunit

I am new to htmlUnit, and as title, I happen to meet some content is not in element. for example,

```
<div class="slide-title">
        <h2> Lady at her dressing table in a garden</h2>
        <p>
           Chinese
           <br>Southern Song dynasty
           <br>mid-12th century
           <br>
           <a href="/collections/search?f[0]=field_artists%253Afield_artist%3A1411">Su Hanchen</a> (Chinese, active 1120s–1160s)
        </p>
</div>
```

There are three information "Chinese", "Southern Song Dynasty", "mid-12th century" which is all in the tag p but separated by tag br. How could I target these three content and get text content?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use XPath, namely [`domNode.getFirstByXPath(path)`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getFirstByXPath(java.lang.String))

```
//div[@class='slide-title']/p/text()[1] = "Chinese"

//div[@class='slide-title']/p/text()[2] = "Southern Song Dynasty"

...
```

PS it's easy to play with XPaths using Chrome Developer Tools. Use `$x("//some-path")` in Console.